# How to keep the toolbar fixed at the top when soft keyboard is appears

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a chat application. I have attached the screenshots. When the keyboard is active the toolbar is not visible. i have tried various solution on stack overflow and other websites but nothing seems to work for me. I have attached the code. Please help.
1.layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_chat_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:background="@color/newColor2">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height" />
        <se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
            android:id="@+id/list_chat_messages"
            style="@style/ListViewWithoutDividerStyle"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_chat"
            style="@style/CenterProgressBarStyle"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_attachment_preview_container"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/layout_chat_send_container"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider_chat_attachments"
                style="@style/HorizontalDividerStyle" />

            <com.flock.android.quickblox.chat.ui.widget.AttachmentPreviewAdapterView
                android:id="@+id/adapter_view_attachment_preview"
                style="@style/MatchWidth" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider_chat"
            style="@style/HorizontalDividerStyle"
            android:layout_above="@+id/layout_chat_send_container" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_chat_send_container"
            style="@style/MatchWidth"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_chat_attachment"
                style="@style/BorderlessImageButtonStyle"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:onClick="onAttachmentsClick"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_attachment"
                android:visibility="gone" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_chat_message"
                style="@style/WeightWidth"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/chat_edit_text_hint"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorActionMode"
                android:inputType="textShortMessage|textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:maxLength="1024"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_margin_small"
                android:singleLine="false" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_chat_send"
                style="@style/BorderlessImageButtonStyle"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:onClick="onSendChatClick"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_sent"
                android:text="@string/chat_send" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

2.Screenshots:
[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: _i have tried various solution on stack overflow_ What u have tried? I can't see in code. Did u try with `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"`

Comment: I try this but cant work... <activity
            android:name=".quickblox.chat.ui.activity.ChatActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"/>

Answer (score 5):

Try below code and make sure you're layout is in the ScrollView as adjustResize always resize the activity's main window to make room for the soft keyboard on screen.

```
  <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove flag `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`  for fullscreen activity, if you have in your code

check you should have  `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` in your activity tag in manifest.

Now try...Hope it helps

Comment: i had the same issue and given solution only solved my problem...in your case if its not solving your problem then try to set **setActionBar** with the toolbar and in xml try to give below (@+id/app_bar) property to StickyListHeadersListView...